DAX - PowerBI - Rolling 3 Month Average Measure for Clustered Bar Line Chart
I have tried every solution from similar questions and none have worked thus far.
I have a table of individual IDs, their Date, and an Action Indicator (0 or 1).
I created a clustered bar and line chart that has the total count of IDs for each month as the bar, and their average action rate as a line.
I want a measure that will create a trailing 3-month average line for the action rates. The closest I have gotten so far is:
Trailing 3 Month Action % = 
VAR CurrentDate = MAX('Table'[Date])
VAR ThreeMonthsAgo = EDATE(CurrentDate, -3)
VAR ActionsInLast3Months = 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Table'[Action_ind]),
        'Table'[Date] > ThreeMonthsAgo && 'Table'[Date] <= CurrentDate
    )
VAR TotalIDsInLast3Months = 
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[ID]),
        'Table'[Date] > ThreeMonthsAgo && 'Table'[Date] <= CurrentDate
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE(ActionsInLast3Months, TotalIDsInLast3Months, 0)

However, the calculation is incorrect. These are examples values this measure outputs into the chart (that don't add up).
| Month | ID  |  Total Actions  | Action Rate | *Dax calculated | *What I expected |
| Jan   | 321 |  182            |    56.70%   |    
| Feb   | 240 |  147            |    62.25%   |    
| Mar   | 350 |  195            |    55.71%   |    59.27%       |  64.61%
| Apr   | 351 |  209            |    59.54%   |    61.83%       |  58.55%
| May   | 280 |  178            |    63.57%   |    64.73%       |  59.33%

I assumed March would be (195+147+182)/(350+240+321) = 64.61%
April would be (209+195+147)/(351+350+240) = 58.55%
May would be   (178+209+195)/(280+351+350) = 59.33%
I have no idea how DAX is getting to their result, and how to get it to match my expectations. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

do you have the date table? you can use DATEADD function to get the previous two months value.

Try this measure:
Trailing 3 Month Action % = 
VAR thisDate = MAX('Table'[Date])
VAR thisDateStart = EOMONTH(thisDate,-3)+1
VAR thisDateEnd = EOMONTH(thisDate,0)

VAR countID = CALCULATE(COUNT('Table'[ID])
        , FILTER(ALL('Table')
            , 'Table'[Date] >= thisDateStart
            && 'Table'[Date] <= thisDateEnd
        )
)

VAR sumActions = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Action_ind])
        , FILTER(ALL('Table')
            , 'Table'[Date] >= thisDateStart
            && 'Table'[Date] <= thisDateEnd
        )
)

RETURN DIVIDE(sumActions, countID)

In this measure, we are getting the start date of the month, 3 months prior. As well as the end date of the current month to ensure we collect all the data before dividing it.
